# Android SDK for determining the music being played around you?

Tags: android, sdk

I'm looking into creating an android app and wanted to make something that could show what people around the user are listening to. Is there any way to do this? I've been looking at the Spotify SDK and it dosen't appear to be possible, but I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Sarah Markers,

To identify the music being played around you, I would suggest you to read this article  http://www.royvanrijn.com/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/ .

I could not find anything on Spotify SDK which can help you with determining the music.